# Using small 2D Array is causing a stack overflow (seg fault before main)?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I've tried everything and I cannot get this to work. For some reason, my code is seg faulting before it even executes the main function. I originally thought that meant stack overflow but I allocated the 2D arrays dynamically as shown below and it's still a problem. They're not even big arrays! just 10x10!
Let me know if you have suggestions.

```
 #include "Recursion.h"
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <fstream>  
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

Recursion::Recursion(string filename){
    //Initaliaze all items in original grid to 0;
    grid = new int *[10];
    for(int e=0; e<10; e++){
        grid[e] = new int[10];
    }

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        grid[i][j]= 0;
    }
}

    ifstream fin(filename);
    string line = "";
    int x = 0; int y = 0;
    while(getline(fin, line)){
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)line.length(); i++){
            if(line[i] == '.'){
                grid[y][x] = 0;
            }
            else {
                grid[y][x] = 1;
            }
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
}
void Recursion::print(){
    //Makes a copy of the array.
    int **gridCopy;
    gridCopy  = new int *[10];
    for(int e=0; e<10; e++){
        grid[e] = new int[10];
    }

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        gridCopy[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        cout << gridCopy[i][j] << " ";
    }
}

int count = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if(gridCopy[i][j] == 1){
            cout << "Group" << count << ": ";
            printGroupWith(gridCopy, i, j);
        }
    }
}

}

void Recursion::printGroupWith(int **arr, int y, int x){
    if(y >= 10 || x >= 10){
        return;
    }
    else if(arr[y][x] == 0){
        return;
    }
    else if(arr[y][x] == 1){
        arr[y][x] = 0;
        cout << "(" << y << ", " << x << ")";
        //Checks to the North
        if(y > 0){
            printGroupWith(arr, y - 1, x);
        }
        //Checks to the South
        if(y < 9){
            printGroupWith(arr, y + 1, x);
        }
        //Checks to the East
        if(x < 9){
            printGroupWith(arr, y, x + 1);
        }
        //Checks to the West
        if(x > 0){
            printGroupWith(arr, y, x - 1);
        }
    }

}


 int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    cout << "hey";
    if(argc == 2){
        cout << "CHECK";
        Recursion A(argv[1]);

    cout << "CHECK1";
    A.print();

    cout << "CHECK2";
}

return 0;

}
```

Here's the header file where I define the array. NOTE: I originally tried allocating to the stack using int name[10][10]; notation.

```
#ifndef RECURSION_H
#define RECURSION_H

 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <array>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 class Recursion{
 private:
    int **grid;


 public:
    Recursion(string filename);
    void print();
    void printGroupWith(int **arr, int y, int x);
 };

 #endif
```

UPDATE :: Here's the sample.txt input file..

```
.........X
...XX....X
..........
....X..X..
...X...X..
.......XX.
....XX....
..........
..........
..........
```

Comment: You're probably accessing the array out-of-bounds in the loop where you read the input. Make sure that `x` or `y` will never be 10 or greater. Or just `cout` the values to make sure.

Comment: What is the file being passed as command line `argv[1]`? On which line exactly is the error?

Comment: I cout in the very beginning of main and nothing gets output. It seems to be happening before execution of main. I'm passing in a txt file that contains '.' and 'X' chars

Comment: `cout` in the loop where you read the data (before `grid[y][x]`). Or better, use a debugger.

Comment: Also are you sure there are extra whitespace in your text file because they would mess up your current algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't account for whitespace because I was debugging it but it was before and I don't think that's the problem. When I use gdb it says..

"'/local_path/sample.txt' is not a core dump: File format not recognized"

Then when I run it and backtrace it, it only tells me...

"No stack."

Comment: cout uses buffers which may not be displayed when expected. The program can be crashing after stuff has been added to the buffer. You may have to explicitly call flush() each time to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The program doesn't crash before main, to see your output statements either include and endl (cout << endl) or call flush on the stream (cout.flush()), it crashes because the file reading loop doesn't reset x:

```
while (getline(fin, line))
{
    x=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)line.length(); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == '.')
        {
            grid[y][x] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            grid[y][x] = 1;
        }
        x++;
    }
    y++;
}
```

After that you'll get a second crash when printing the data, because you're assigning the new allocated data to grid instead of gridCopy:

```
for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++)
{
    gridCopy[e] = new int[10];
}
```